# Estimate the unknown probability and its uncertainty of getting Head when tossing the coin

Tags: confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Consider a coin that shows Heads with unknown probability  when tossed. After tossing this coin 100 times, Heads have shown up 43 times. The unknown parameter is contained in what interval with a [confidence level of 95%]? (maybe I shouldn't use the term 'confidence level', the original question states: a probability of 95%)

[Original problem](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/resources/mit18_650f16_pset1): problem 2.4

I tried to solve it like the following, but not sure if the answer is correct. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

${p}$ follows beta distribution where ${\alpha = 43 + 1 = 44}$, and ${\beta = 100-43+1 = 58}$

mean of beta distribution ${ \bar p = \frac{\alpha}{\beta + \alpha} = 0.4314 }$, variance of beta distribution = ${\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2 (\alpha + \beta+1)} = 0.04880019427^2}$, thus ${
\sigma = 0.04880019427}$

Using central limit theorem: 95% of confidence level, ${\bar{p} - 2\sigma \sim \bar{p} + 2\sigma }$

Here are my questions:

1. Should I use the mean of p or the mode of p here? mean = ${\frac{\alpha}{\beta + \alpha}}$ while the mode = ${\frac{\alpha - 1}{\beta + \alpha -2}}$
2. Does the central limit theorem apply here in beta distribution?

Comment: I do not see why a beta distribution comes up at all. This problem seems like a straightforward calculation of a confidence interval for the probability parameter of a Bernoulli distribution. // Why should $p$ follow a beta distribution just because $p\in[0,1]?$

Comment: Here is a good explanation of beta distribution, I think it fits quite well in this case. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juF3r12nM5A&ab_channel=Serrano.Academy

Comment: But why should your parameter follow a beta distribution? What is your parameter has a tri-modal distribution? Further, in a frequentist setting (since you’re calculating a confidence interval, not a credible interval), why should the parameter have any distribution at all?

Comment: After reading your edit, are you doing Bayesian statistics? Introductory statistics? Do you know what confidence or credible intervals are?

Comment: @ Dave I'm following the <statistics for application> lecture and homework but wasn't sure about my attempt at this problem (and it could be a wrong answer). Could you please kindly give your solution? Many thanks